# How to find the opposite of a number in a list of list in OCaml?

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm trying to find the opposite of a number in a list of list. I want to iterate through every element of the list of list, and check if the opposite of this element is in the list of list.

This is what I've done so far:

```ml
let rec findOpposite l  =
match l with
| [] -> false
| f::x::ll -> if (List.mem (-x) f = false && List.mem (-x) ll = false) then true else findOpposite ll;;
```

I naively assumed 'f' was representing all the previous elements of the list...

I also explored this solution: flatten the list, to make it a bit more simple. But now I'm kinda lost.

What's expected here is to iterate through every element of the list, check if its opposite is in there, if so -> true, otherwise continue until we reach the end.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be good to write a description of your high-level plan. Flattening the list is a tactic, but not really a high level plan. For example you might traverse your list of lists and compute a set, or maybe a couple of sets. Then you can answer the question with simple tests of set properties. If you decide on what should be in the sets, that would be a high level plan.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Well, this function would be used in propositional logic. This one has a specific goal of finding a pure literal, hence why I'm trying to find its opposite in the list of lists.

Comment: That's too high level! :-) I mean a plan for getting the answer you want from the list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't an assignment, I can give one possible solution. If I understand correctly, you want to know if a set of integers is closed under negation. You can calculate the set, then negate the set, then see if the two sets are equal.

```
module ISet =
    Set.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end)

let get_set ll =
    List.fold_left
       (List.fold_left (fun is i -> ISet.add i is))
       ISet.empty
       ll

let negate_set is = ISet.map (fun i -> -i) is

let closed_set is = ISet.equal is (negate_set is)
```

You can try it out like this:

```
# closed_set (get_set [[1;2]; [-2;-2]; [3;-3;-1]]);;
- : bool = true
# closed_set (get_set [[1;2]; [-2;-2]; [3;-3]]);;
- : bool = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose using some library functions to improve Jeffrey's answer. I don't want to edit and interfere with his work, and it's beyond the reach of comments.

```
module ISet = Set.Make(Int)

let get_set ll =
  ll 
  |> List.map ISet.of_list
  |> List.fold_left ISet.union ISet.empty
```

I would also suggest that we could use `ISet.for_all` and `ISet.mem` to define `closed_set`:

```
let closed_set is = 
  ISet.for_all (fun x -> ISet.mem ~-x is) is
```

And testing:

```
# [[1;2]; [-2;-2]; [3;-3;-1]] 
  |> get_set 
  |> closed_set;;
- : bool = true
```